# Why does an observed acceleration not imply observation of a force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I read this in Kleppners book *Introduction to mechanics*

> For instance, if we observe that an air track rider of mass *m* starts to accelerate at rate $a$, it might be tempting to conclude that we have just observed a force $F = ma$. Tempting, but wrong. The reason is that forces always arise from real physical interactions between systems. Interactions are scientifically significant: accelerations are merely their consequence.

I think that is invalid because it breaks Newton'ss first law.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this description breaks Newton's first law?

Comment: I assumed a inertial referencial frame. Therefore  if a non-zero, then F is non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think that is invalid because it breaks Newton'ss first law.

Newton's first law is only valid in, well... newtonian referential frames (RF).
Imagine one of your friends starts riding a bike faster and faster. In your RF, he is accelerating. But in his RF, he is obviously at rest, and YOU are accelerating the other way. In his RF, you have a non-zero acceleration a. Yet, what force is acting on you ? None, right ?

That might be what the author had in mind. Acceleration is relative to your RF. It does not necessarily mean force, especially in the context of non-inertial RF. You will see that a lot when talking about the centrifugal "force", for instance which is... **not** a force ! It is merely a manifestation of the non-inertial RF in rotation.